# ArrayList<DisplayMode> null pointer exception in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Inside of this class I have

```
public DisplayMode resolutions[] = {
    new DisplayMode(1920, 1080, 32, 0),
    new DisplayMode(1680, 1050, 32, 0),
};

public ArrayList<DisplayMode> list;
```

and the constructor

```
14 - public myClass(){
15 -     list.add(resolutions[0]);
16 - }
```

I'm getting a null pointer exception on line 15. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add elements to your `list` without instantiating it (it's `null`)

```
public ArrayList<DisplayMode> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I suggest you use the `List` interface. Also, Java naming convention would be `MyClass` and you could initialize `list` in the constructor with [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) (which I suggest you not make `public`) like

```
private List<DisplayMode> list;
public MyClass() {
  list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(resolutions));
}
```